# xmlParseFile vs xmlReadFile (libxml2)

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm writing some C code using the libxml2 library to read an XML file.  There seem to be two different functions for this purpose, [xmlParseFile](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseFile) and [xmlReadFile](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadFile), and and I'm not sure of the difference between them (besides the fact that xmlReadFile() takes some additional parameters).

The examples on the libxml2 website sometimes use xmlParseFile and some use xmlReadFile.

So when should you use xmlParseFile and when should you use xmlReadFile? 
I haven't been able to find anything that explains this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xmlReadFile() is a bit more powerful as it is able to take an URL instead of a local file path, and allows to specify more options (http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParserOption), so I tend to use it instead of xmlParseFile(). That said, if you  are parsing a local XML file and not using the parser options, you will be fine with xmlParseFile().

Comment: Thanks, the only other info I've been able to find is here (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.lib.xml.general/16586) where the author of libxml2 says "Use xmlReadFile, it's the modern API for parsing" which seems to imply that xmlParseFile() is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I have xml arriving in character buffer 'msg' on TCP pipe so I use libxml2 call xmlReadDoc() instead as following with options XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS and XML_PARSE_OLD10

```
xmlDocPtr parsed_xml_dom;
parsed_xml_dom = xmlReadDoc((xmlChar *)(msg), NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS| XML_PARSE_OLD10);
```

Answer (score 0):

xmlReadFile() is more powerful and latest version for parsing the XML. I am also using it in place of xmlParseFile().