# libxml2 XML_PARSE_HUGE option for xmlParseMemory

Tags: libxml2

C++ on Centos 6.4, libxml2.x86_64 2.7.6-12.el6_4.1:

I'm trying to fix an old C++ program that occasionally gets XML parser errors on large xml files, seems to need the XML_PARSE_HUGE option set. But I can't see any place to set it! The code that's failing is using the xmlParseMemory function which only has 2 parameters - the char array to parse and its size.

Is there some way to set the XML_PARSE_HUGE option globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to switch to [`xmlReadMemory`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory) which has an `options` parameter. Simply convert calls like

```
xmlParseMemory(buffer, size);
```

to

```
xmlReadMemory(buffer, size, NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_HUGE);
```

(I think `xmlParseMemory` predates the parser options and is only retained for backward compatibility. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315206/xmlparsefile-vs-xmlreadfile-libxml2/19363446).)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. If the libxml2 maintainers are watching, they may want to suggest in their docs that xmlParseMemory is deprecated.