# Linux - bash script to remove each line before the same line from a file

Tags: xml, linux, xslt-1.0

I have an invalid xml file (it's an output of another process), I need to validate it in linux (bash script).
In the invalid file there are empty tags - without closing tags like:

```
<om>
<om>
<some data>
</some data>
</om>
```

I tried to run the following commands:

1. Using xsl:

```
xsltproc prepare_v270.xsl test.xml  > /tmp/test.xml.bak
test.xml:413282: parser error : Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option
    <om>
    ^
```

unable to parse test.xml
2. Using xmlstarlet

```
 sudo xmlstarlet ed -d '//*[not(normalize-space())]' test.xml
test.xml:413282.5: Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option
    <om>
    ^
```

And so on

I tried to write a bash script to remove each `<om>` line before line with `<om>` word by the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
/\<om\>/ {
#append the next line
        N
# look for "<om>" followed by "<om>"
        /\<om\>.*\<om\>/ {
#       print
                P
#       then delete the first line
                D
        }
}' <old.xml >new.xml
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: By the [definition of XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-documents) there is no such thing as "invalid XML". Either a character string is a valid XML document or it is not XML at all. Anything that can correctly processes XML will fail because the input is not XML. Or to put it another way: the examples you give show tools saying this is not XML, and have successfully shown the input is not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libxml2 XML\_PARSE\_HUGE option for xmlParseMemory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24531634/608639). It is not clear to me how `XML_PARSE_HUGE` relates to the other part of the question about invalid XML. Perhaps you should edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. If there is no invalid xml maybe I need to write a loop in bash script or using sed to remove any <om> before <om>

Comment: If the error is systemic i.e. every `</om>` needs to be followed by another `</om>` throughout the entire document, a simple lexical replacement like `sed 's%</om>%&&%' invalid.xml >new.xml` might work. Without more infolmation about how exactly the input is broken, there is no way really to give concrete advice.

Comment: Instead of removing something, I'd try to add something to make it valid XML. That way you don't lose information

Comment: If that program does not produce valid XML, it's likely that it has a lot of other issues as well, like wrong escaping of special characters, wrong encoding etc.

Comment: I want to use sed command for remove each <omt> tag before <omt> tag without anything between them. I'm looking for this solution... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - to remove a line in file if the next line is the same.
This logic removes the open tag before the same open tag.

```
pre=
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   # echo "Line read from file: $line"
   # if line does not contain line pre
   if ! { [ -n "$pre" ] && [[ "$line" == "$pre" ]] ; }; then
      # echo "   <$pre> not found!"
      echo "$line"
      pre=$line
   fi
done <old.xml >new.xml
```

Thanks for all!!